# Conectar Xamarin ao Mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, osx, mac

Estou tentando conectar o Xamarin ao Mac utilizando o Visual Studio. O Mac é listado no Xamarin User Agent, mas ao informar o usuário e a senha recebo essa mensagem:

> Starting Broker 4.0.1.96 in port 51743...
>   Couldn't connect to macbook-ricardo.local. Please try again.
>   Disconnected from Mac macbook-ricardo.local (172.19.2.222)
>   bash: /Users/ricardo.lima/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Broker/4.0.1.96/Broker.exe: cannot execute binary file

Lembrando que o Mac está habilitado para conexão remota no usuário ricardo.lima, conforme solicitado pelo Visual Studio.

Comment: `ricardo.lima` é administrador?

Comment: Sim, é administrador

Comment: Ricardo,
Você verificou se algum firewall está bloqueando conexões ssh ?
Veja este endereço, se ajuda ? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/ Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Conecte no MAC e inicie o Xamarin que assim o `Host` será iniciado junto ao serviço. Segue o [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) para mais informações.

Comment: Voce tem o XCode e o Xamarin instalado no Mac? Precisa dos dois! Bati muita cabeca com isso!